# How to profile AngularJS on mobile

Tags: javascript, angularjs, profiling

I'm developing an AngularJS app. It works pretty smooth on desktop, but awfully slow on mobile (I guess due to lower CPU specs).

I've read some articles about AngularJS performance optimization, such as [this one](http://www.binpress.com/tutorial/speeding-up-angular-js-with-simple-optimizations/135), but I still don't get how to profile the app to find out which of the possible issues described in the article is the bottleneck in my case.

In Chrome DevTools profile I can see that each `$digest` takes at least 500ms (see below), but how do I interpret what the functions inside the `$digest` actually mean?

[image: Chrome DevTools profile]

Comment: $scope.$digest() function iterates through all the watches in the $scope object, and its child $scope objects (if it has any). When $digest() iterates over the watches, it calls the value function for each watch. If the value returned by the value function is different than the value it returned the last time it was called, the listener function for that watch is called.

Comment: Ok, I have something like 14 watchers. But how to find out which of them is the bottleneck?

Comment: those watchers are totally different than you are saying..you are talking about `$scope.$watch`..angular directives also uses watcher internally like ng-repeat,ng-if, ng-show etc. Take a look at this link http://teropa.info/blog/2014/01/26/the-three-watch-depths-of-angularjs.html